# R - dataframe making a additional column with if or else loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following simple dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("StudyID" = paste("Study", seq(1:100), sep = "_"),
             "Score" = sample(c(1:30),100, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a additional column in the dataframe: df. This column needs to contain the value:

- "great" if the value in the column Score is larger than 20.
- "bad" if the value is smaller than 10.
- "neutral" if otherwise (so between 10 and 20).

This new column NEEDS to be made with a IF or ELSE-loop or both.

Thanks in advance!!
Your help is really appreciated!

-All the code I used is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution without any additional function or packages is via subsetting and nested `ifelse`:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$Score > 20, "great",
                 ifelse(df$Score < 10, "bad", "neutral"))
```

Comment: First of all, we seem to have posted the answers at the same time. Second, it is different in that it is without `transform`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the temporal coincidence. Do you really think that I was not aware of `ifelse` before your post appeared and that I committed intellectual theft by using it for my post? You could check in my previous posts: I've been using `ifelse` a great many times--in fact it's one of my fav functions.

Comment: Not in exactly the same way--see comment above. I think this issue is not really worth our time. I have been--and intend to remain--a great admirer of your work on SO. I for my part would like to finish this conversation on that positive note.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, newcol = ifelse(Score > 20, "great", 
                        ifelse(Score < 10, "bad", "neutral")))
```

Or `case_when` from `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(newcol = case_when(Score > 20 ~ "great",
                            Score < 10 ~ "bad", 
                            TRUE ~ "neutral"))
```

Comment: Sorry both cases wont create a additional column with the results in the same row with great bad or neutral.

Comment: @JoeBens Assign the results `df1 <- transform(df, newcol = ifelse(Score > 20, "great", 
                        ifelse(Score < 10, "bad", "neutral")))`

Comment: Thanks! It worked I tried that too, but something went wrong I guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fifelse` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newcol := fifelse(Score > 20, "great", 
                        fifelse(Score < 10, "bad", "neutral"))]
```

Or with `fcase`

```
setDT(df)[, newcol := fcase(Score > 20, "great",
                            Score < 10, "bad",
                            "neutral")]
```